# Do we ever see Ishamael channel Saidin?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

**Warning: Spoilers allowed in answers**

Ever since The Eye of the World prologue, Ishamael/Moridin seems to channel the True Power exclusively.

We know that Elan Morin Tedronai was considered Lews Therin's equal in the One Power. But I'm working on a theory for why

> Rand couldn't channel Saidin after 'switching bodies' with Moridin.

So, do we ever see Elan Morin, either as Ishamael or Moridin, actually wield Saidin?

---

Just got back from a vacation to the US. I was lucky enough to be in San Diego when Brandon Sanderson was signing, so I asked him. He "MAFO'd" this specific question. So I asked if Moridin was in fact no able to channel Saidin. He responded with a grin and, "That's a very good question." I think this might be the new form of RAFO.

So, if we could find an instance of Moridin channeling Saidin, then this question can be put to bed. If not, it might suggest that he couldn't, but it's not proof.

Comment: Is your suggestion where it (e.g. The Guide) says Elan was Lews Therin's equal in the One Power, the text actually means Saidar?

Comment: I'm working on the theory that Moridin could only channel the True Power.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm trying to keep the spoilers low, but it's really hard - book 7 matter discussed below.*

I think we did. I don't have a specific quote for that though.

> Check the end of The Great Hunt and The Dragon Reborn maybe? We have battles with Ishamael, and I don't remember Rand remarking use of True Power or any hints of that in the text.

Early in the books, Ishamael isn't allowed exclusive use to True Power vs the other Forsaken.

> Only when coming back as Moridin is he annointed as the Nae'blis, and given unlimited access to the True Power while at the same time the others denied.

Rand is surprised when they meet

> at Shadar Logoth

that he didn't feel him at all. IMHO, he wouldn't have been if previous encounters had been similar.

---

After re-reading the ending of TDR, I *think* Rand is feeling Ishamael channel Saidin, when he copies what he does to enter Tel'aran'rhiod. The actual words used by RJ are ambiguous, because Rand isn't still knowledgeable enough about Saidin, but it seems unlikely (IMHO) that Rand at this stage would feel the "warping of reality" that opening a Travelling portal causes rather than the actual weaving of the Power.

It's still weak evidence, and is certainly debatable.

Comment: I think in your first spoiler block you mean The Dragon Reborn not tSR. At the time Rand thought Ba'alzamon was the DO, so not feeling him channel wasn't unusual.

Comment: I will have to go back and read the specific passages, but I'm still not sure if he's channeling Saidin.

Comment: @NikolaiDante You're right, I was thinking of the Stone of Tear 'events' which are in TDR, not TSR, editing.

Comment: Note that Ishy was definitely using the true power as Ishamel, as the flame-eyes effect that Rand sees early on was almost certainly an effect of the *saa* that comes from True-Power channeling. I think Lanfear even mentions Ishy's heavy use of the TP at one point.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield There's no doubt that he was using it, but I remember a phrase saying he now 'exclusively' uses it, which means that before he didn't.

Comment: @jv42 Aha, and this is shortly after he re-emerged as Moridin. So maybe Moridin couldn't channel the One Power at all?

Comment: @anthony-arnold Well, that's the complement to the original question. As Moridin was (probably) intended to be Nae'blis and thus, have his access to True Power secured, maybe he wouldn't need Saidin. OTOH, with Cyndane, we have 'proof' that the ability to channel is a matter of the soul, not of the body (actual 'proof' is in ToM if memory serves).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure how solid this proof was. Maybe Ishamael was burnt out? This would explain why Moridin is so pissed at Nynaeve for discovering how to heal severing. More investigation!

Comment: @anthony-arnold Ok ok, I'll open my books and check the battles!

Comment: Completed re-read of TGH, no mention of any kind of Power, Rand (which POV is used all along) is still learning what's the Power is, he wouldn't be able to tell the difference. I'm continuing with TDR.

Comment: Just got back from a vacation to the US. I was lucky enough to be in San Diego when Brandon Sanderson was signing, so I asked him. He "MAFO'd" this specific question. So I asked if Moridin was in fact not able to channel Saidin at all. He responded with a grin and, "That's a very good question." I think this might be the new form of RAFO.

Comment: @anthony-arnold Lucky you indeed! In this instance, not denying is almost admitting it...

Comment: @jv42 True, it's pretty suspicious. It could also be because it touches on the epilogue, and Brandon seems to be deliberately tight-lipped about anything to do with the ending.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes.

I know this is a late answer to an old question, but I was doing some unrelated review of *A Memory of Light* and there is (what I feel to be) an incontestable example:

> Moridin scooped *Callandor* up off the floor. It burst alight with the One Power. [...] 
>  He trailed off, then looked up at the sword, perhaps in awe. "It can amplify the True Power. A True Power *sa'angreal*? How? Why? He laughed louder. [...]
>  The sword's glow turned a violent crimson. Rand could feel the power emanating from Moridin as he drew in the True Power. (*AMoL*, page 975).

This example is pretty straightforward. As a *sa'angreal*, *Callandor*'s only purpose is to amplify the amount of the One Power that can be drawn by its wielder. *Angreal* and *sa'angreal* are useless to people that can't channel, unlike some *ter'angreal*. The sequence of events makes it clear that

> Moridin draws *Saidin* through *Callandor* first. This is the only explanation for it suddenly bursting alight. At this point Moridin does not know that he can draw the True Power through it as well, so it cannot be glowing due to using that instead. Soon after, when he realizes that *Callandor* can amplify the True Power as well as *Saidin*, he does so, and the light emanating from *Callandor* changes to a violent crimson.

So here we have a pretty airtight indication that

> Up to the point immediately preceding his death, Moridin can still draw on *Saidin*.

As we know from Slayer's narration, ability to channel the One Power cannot be granted by the Dark One. Thus, since he can do so at that moment, Ishamael/Moridin must have been able to draw on *Saidin* at all prior points in time as well.

Comment: Nice catch, this seems definitive enough.

Comment: @jv42 It really helped to have access to the completed series :)